# Get values from table column if row checked

Tags: php

I am using PHP to get values from the table and need to process them further.
If row is checked I need to get values from columns Quantity and FMK Code.

Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="success">
            <th>#<br/></th> 
            <th>Article  </th>
            <th>Name  </th> 
            <th>Quantity</th> 
            <th>FMK CODE<br/></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            $i = 1; 
            while($r=$q->fetch()){  ?>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="from-control" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $r['id']?>"></td>
                <td><?=$r['Article']?></td>  
                <td><?=$r['Name']?></td>     
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?=$r['quantity'];?>" name="quantity"></td>   
                <td> 
                    <select class="form-control col-lg-2" name="childCode"><?php getChildCodes($r["code"]) ?></select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

On submit I need to get values from "quantity and childCode" for each row selected.

```
<button type="submit" name="getValues"> Submit </button>
```

PhP processing:

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST['getValues'])) {

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
        $childCode = $_POST['childCode'];

        $values = array(); 

        foreach($id as $id) {
            foreach($quantity as $quant){
                foreach($childCode as $code){
                    array_push($values, $id,$quant,$code);
            }
        }           
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($values);
        echo "</pre>";          
    }
?>
```

values output. In output I get all values from table, no matter if they are checked or not which is wrong. Also array print was not well, values from one name form array. I need array to be formed first element of id, quantity, child code to b one array. [0]=>"177239","10.000",113

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "177239"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "177240"
      [2]=>
      string(6) "177241"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "10.000"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "100.000"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "10.000"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "113"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "87"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "91"
  }
}
```

Comment: _“In output I get all values from table, no matter if they are checked or not which is wrong.”_ - normal text input fields will _always_ submit a value, so this is not “wrong”. (It might not be what you _want_, but that and “wrong” are two different things.) _“I need array to be formed first element of id, quantity, child code to b one array. [0]=>"177239","10.000",113”_ - then you need to name your form fields accordingly to begin with. `foo[0][0]` for the checkbox, `foo[0][1]` for the text field, `foo[0][2]` for the select, and so on for the following rows, `foo[1][0]`, `foo[1][1]`, etc.

Comment: @ Thanks, but I don't understand quite well

Comment: What are you having problems with? Did you try it with field names like I suggested, and then checked what result you get? (var_dump or print_r of $_POST, so that you can see what the structure is like.)

Comment: @misorude Could you write example of naming

Comment: I already gave you an example, and Trent’s answer provides a different way. Again: _Try_ something with those suggestions, and use var_dump to see what structure you get with that in $_POST.

Comment: The indexes don’t need to be purely numerical, you can use stuff like `name="data[0][id]"`, `name="data[0][quantity]"` etc. as well, if you want the data that belongs together, grouped together as well.

Answer (score 0):

misorude is pointing out that you need to name the form elements in a style that builds a PHP array. That is done with the `[]` characters as mentioned. So the first row would have element names like `<input name="id[0]" ...`, `<input name="quantity[0]" ...`. The second row would have element names like `<input name="id[1]"` and `<input name="quantity[1]"`

Also make sure the `foreach` block doesn't overwrite the `$id` variable :)

```
foreach($id as $id) // Oops!
```